# External database Android app

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have written an app for reading data from database in JSON format. As I have no experience in PHP and SQL, I am having a hard time to find a dummy database with PHP script online for testing my app.

So my question is, is there a way of testing my code or if you know of any PHP script on a server, which reads from database in JSON format?

Code:

```
String temp ="";
temp = sbuilder.toString();

String returned[]= temp.split("#END_HERE#", temp.length());

    try 
    {//Toast.makeText(DisplaySubjectsInList.this, "In json"+jsonArray.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(returned[0]);



        ListOfNames = new String[jsonArray.length()];



        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ListOfNames[i] = json.getString("name"); 


            Toast.makeText(Name.this, ListOfSubjects[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Name.this, "json failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi there. This question will probably close, as there appears to be no research prior effort. You can find PHP tutorials that will read data from a MySQL database very easily, and then you can just send the results into `json_encode`. Give it a _real_ go, and then ask a focussed question if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm downvoting this, since it is essentially a duplicate of your last question - please only ask questions once!

Comment: how come you have written an app without having JSON at hand

Answer (score 0):

Here're your problems, and their solutions:

#### Problem 1. Generate Dummy Data.

**Solution :** Go to http://www.generatedata.com/#generator and generate whatever dummy data you like, you can select columns, types etc. And you can save the output in  **CSV, Excel, Json, HTML, Programming Languages, XML or SQL**.

#### Problem 2. You wanted to access those data over a URL

**Solution :** Go to [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) and create a page where you add your generated JSON as the HTML contents. You will get a URL using which you can download the JSON in your application.

(I have generated a sample dummy data at [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator) and created a simple page at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) and pasted those data there. See it now: http://jsbin.com/ubucaj/2 )

#### Note:

In case you want to test the data inside your app itself and don't want to access it over the internet, just save it in your `/assets` folder and access it.

Comment: And, in that link, you need to add some delimiter string, so that you can chip off the extra HTML tags added by jsbin.com. I added `#END_HERE#` as the delimiter.

Comment: not working. I am getting JsonException: `org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 32 of  {
`

Comment: That's the error in the code as I can see. Please double check your code. Thanks.

Comment: **I hope the purpose of your question is served now.** Please put some effort to research on how to parse Json data rather than posting it and expecting others to solve all of your problems. Thanks.

Comment: I have searched alot today. As far as I think my code is fine. I don't know why I am getting error. I have tried another json data too, but there I get JsonException for converting string in to JsonObject. For that json data, the code I have written is : `JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(myStringContainingJsonString);`
`JsonArray array = obj.getJsonArray("contacts")`. Kindly help me

Comment: Kindly help me. I will be very greatful to you & if you can, link me to a good json tutorial cuz the one I found on internet haven't been helpful either